# Convert time in date as 00:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date column in below varchar format. How to convert it to datetime format and replace the time as 00:00:00?

```
Dateformats (varchar)
2011-08-01 00:00:00
2000-11-16 07:39:44
2020-06-06 07:51:42.644
2020-05-26 06:55:38.08
```

Expected result

```
Dateformats (datetime)
2011-08-01 00:00:00.000
2000-11-16 00:00:00.000
2020-06-06 00:00:00.000
2020-05-26 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast to a `date`:

```
cast(left(datecol, 10) as date)
```

You don't actually need the `left()`, so this works:

```
cast(datecol as date)
```

But I like the `left()` to be explicit about the conversion.

If you actually want the time component, cast back:

```
cast(cast(left(datecol, 10) as date) as datetime)
```

Or, if you want the value as a string:

```
concat(left(datecol, 10), ' 00:00:00.000')
```

Note:  You shouldn't be storing date/time values as strings.  You should be using the built-in types.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to convert from Datetime to Date, and again to Datetime/Datetime2:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(MyDateTime AS date) as datetime) My_New_DateTime_Without_Time
```